# Stripe payment intent problem during payment

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-payment-intent

I have a payment system with stripe payment intents, where I store the CC data in a stripe customer, and then complete the payment with `StripeService.charge_customer`.

One customer must have had troubles with their CC, so the payment remained pending for a while before it was completed.

In the meanwhile they closed the page an went on with their business, so my application hadn't been updated and the payment doesn't figure.

I have on DB the stripe customer id, and nothing else about this payment, is there a way to verify that the payment was completed successfully?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the Dashboard page for that customer, which will contain a list of all associated payments.

Alternatively you can use the API. [List all Payment Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/list) and pass the `customer` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/list#list_payment_intents-customer), which will return only Payment Intents associated with that Customer object.